# How to increase the size of input and button

Tags: sapui5

I have a simple form, that looks as follows:
[image]

On the large screen, it looks pretty small. I would like to increase the size and width.

This is the code:

```
<Page title="{i18n>authorization}">
        <content>
            <VBox alignItems="Center">
                <f:SimpleForm id="registration" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanXL="3" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3" labelSpanS="12"
                    adjustLabelSpan="true" emptySpanXL="3" emptySpanL="3" emptySpanM="3" emptySpanS="0" columnsXL="1" columnsL="1" columnsM="1"
                    singleContainerFullSize="true">
                    <f:content>
                        <Label text=""/>
                        <Text text="{i18n>userAuthorize}"/>
                        <Label text=""/>
                        <Input placeholder="Enter your email address" id="email" type="Email" value="{confirm>/email}" liveChange="onHandleLiveChangeEmail"/>
                        <Label text=""/>
                        <Button type="Accept" enabled="{confirm>/enable}" text="{i18n>confirm}" press="handlePressAuthorization"
                            ariaDescribedBy="acceptButtonDescription genericButtonDescription">
                            <layoutData>
                                <FlexItemData growFactor="1"/>
                            </layoutData>
                        </Button>
                    </f:content>
                </f:SimpleForm>
            </VBox>
        </content>
    </Page>
```

**Update**

I have removed simple form and placed the controls in VBOX.

```
    <Page title="{i18n>authorization}">
        <content>
            <VBox alignItems="Center">
                <Label text=""/>
                <Text text="{i18n>userAuthorize}"/>
                <Label text=""/>
                <Input placeholder="Enter your email address" id="email" type="Email" value="{confirm>/email}" liveChange="onHandleLiveChangeEmail"/>
                <Label text=""/>
                <Button type="Accept" enabled="{confirm>/enable}" text="{i18n>confirm}" press="handlePressAuthorization"
                    ariaDescribedBy="acceptButtonDescription genericButtonDescription">
                    <layoutData>
                        <FlexItemData growFactor="1"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Button>
            </VBox>
        </content>
    </Page>
```

The controls still looks very small:

[image]

How can I increase the size of controls?

Comment: Have you tried to play with `width` and `height` in % ?

Comment: if using VBox (your updated code), you probably dont need the Label controls => these are used in a Simple Form to start a new Row of the Form)

Answer (score 0):

The properties `labelSpan<ScreenSize>` and `emptySpan<ScreenSize>` are the one which control the width of the actual elements within a "row" of the form.

More info here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm

For example, for M you have label span of 3 and empty span of 3 => leaving 6 out of total 12 for the actual elements. Try reducing `labelSpanM` and `emptySpanM` to increase the width taken by the element `Text`, `Button` and `Input`

That being said, I don't think the choice of simple Form was a wise choice here - why don't you put the three elements directly into the VBox?

That also being said, in case you are implementing an authentication screen inside an application, you should rethink this and let authentication layers take care of that (wherever your app is running)

**Update after Question update**: depending on what you want to achieve, you could simply add a css class to the control and add some css. that is the "manual" way. you could add a custom theme and style the buttons there. you could add custom extensions of the standard controls, e.g. a custom button as extension of standard button. and completely change the rendering there. I think, this are more or less the possibilities

Comment: thanks for answer. What do you mean with authentication layers?

Comment: For example, if your app runs on an ABAP server, the server has authentication mechanisms. if your app runs on SAP Cloud Platform, it has authentication mechanisms. If it runs on some other (cloud) platform, the platform also has authentication mechanisms. Think SAML / OIDC / X509 Client certificate or even Basic Authentication - whatever the actual mechanism, it should never be taken care of by the actual application. There are exceptions, e.g. you are implementing the frontend of such an authentication layer.

Comment: aha...I got it. The app can be accessed from every from the company. So to solve my problem, I have to create custom css, right?